# How to create a dataframe with pandas.date_range for previous years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe with date from previous years. For example something like this -

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': pd.date_range('2021-09-21', periods=-5, freq='Y')})`

but negative period is not supported. How to achieve that?

Comment: Nicer should be `df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': pd.date_range(end='2021-09-21', periods=5, freq='Y')})`

Comment: How to get the exact date? Its giving me the end of year date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `end` parameter in `date_range` aand then add `DateOffset`:

```
d = pd.to_datetime('2021-09-21')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': pd.date_range(end=d, periods=5, freq='Y') +
                            pd.DateOffset(day=d.day, month=d.month)})
print (df)
       Years
0 2016-09-21
1 2017-09-21
2 2018-09-21
3 2019-09-21
4 2020-09-21
```

Or if need also actual year to last value of column use `YS` for start of year:

```
d = pd.to_datetime('2021-09-21')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': pd.date_range(end=d, periods=5, freq='YS') +
                   pd.DateOffset(day=d.day, month=d.month)})


print (df)
       Years
0 2017-09-21
1 2018-09-21
2 2019-09-21
3 2020-09-21
4 2021-09-21
```